# How to attenuate a cheap MP3-player speaker?

Tags: speakers

I have a cheap single-chip MP3-playing speaker. The kind you you get off eBay for $10. I want to make the output quieter (so I don't always have to adjust the digital volume controls).

The amp is a [LTK8002D](http://www.datasheetcafe.com/ltk8002d-datasheet-audio-amplifier/) Class AB Audio Amplifier

I want to do this in a way that doesn't damage the circuitry. I only have basic electronics knowledge.

Should I do this with a potential divider? If so, should the total match the measured impedence of the speaker? The spec sheet says the speaker is 4 ohms.

Or should I do this with an inline resistor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this simple thing, where audio quality probably isn't very noticeable, just put an inline resistor in series with one of the speaker wires.
A 4ohm should cut the sound roughly in half.  But depending on your preference you may want a larger value. 
Make sure the resistor power is large enough for that amp.  It says it's a 3W, but I doubt that it is being used at that level.  Since the power will be split between the resistor and the speaker, you can probably use a 1/2W.

Sounds like a fun experiment, play and have fun!

Comment: Placing resistor in series with speaker might distort frequency responce of the speaker.

Comment: It did, a bit. But it's only a quick and dirty job.

Answer (score 2):

According to the datasheet for the abovementioned LTK8002D, easiest yet correct way to make it queiter is to decrease Rf resistor value (alternatively, increase Ri value).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that at some point if the sound quality does get too bad.